# unable to redirect response in rest controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I made two `RestController` apis. On response of second api I wanted first api's response (which is a `json` response), so I tried to use `HttpServletResponse.redirect`. I also set required `content type` to it. But on second api response I got `Unsupported Media Type` `Content type 'null' not supported`.

**first API**

```
@GetMapping(value="checkStatus/{msisdn}",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler> fetchOcsByDate2(@PathVariable(value="msisdn",required=true)String msisdn){
        long l_time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Object[]> list = repository.getSingleCallDetail(msisdn);
        if(list==null || list.size()==0) {
            System.out.println("NO RECORD FOUND");
        }
        JSONObject objMain = new JSONObject();
        for(Object[] objArr: list) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            String msisdn_ = objArr[0]==null?null:objArr[0].toString();
            String songId = objArr[1]==null?null:objArr[1].toString();
            String songName = objArr[2]==null?null:objArr[2].toString();
            String status = objArr[3]==null?null:objArr[3].toString();
            String lang = objArr[4]==null?null:objArr[4].toString();
            String startDate = objArr[5]==null?null:objArr[5].toString();
            objMain.put("status", status);
            objMain.put("language", lang);

            obj.put("id", songId);
            obj.put("msisdn", msisdn);
            obj.put("songName", songName);
            objMain.put("subscription", obj);
        }
        long l_time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long l_diff = l_time_end-l_time_start;
        if(list!=null && list.size()>0) {
            return new  ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.OK, ResponseStatusEnum.SUCCESSFUL, ApplicationResponse.SUCCESSFUL, objMain,l_diff+" ms"),HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        if(list==null || list.size()==0) {
            return new  ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed, "not found",l_diff+" ms"),HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);            
        }
        return  new ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed," > Bad request",l_diff+" ms"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

*no problem in output. ran smooth*

**second API**

```
@GetMapping(value="verifyOtp/{msisdn}/{otp}",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void verifyOtp(@PathVariable(value="msisdn",required=true)String msisdn,
        @PathVariable(value="otp",required=true)String otp,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    long l_time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long l_time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long l_diff = l_time_end-l_time_start;
    List<Object[]> list = repository.verifyOtp(msisdn,otp);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");


    if(list!=null && list.size()>0) {
        for(Object[] obj:list) {
            String strDate = obj[3]==null?null:obj[3].toString();
            Date dtDb = sdf.parse(strDate);
            Date dtNow = new Date();
            String strDtNow = sdf.format(dtNow);
            dtNow = sdf.parse(strDtNow);

            long ldtDb = dtDb.getTime();
            long ldtNow = dtNow.getTime();
            if(ldtDb>ldtNow) {
                System.out.println("success within time");
                int ii = repository.updateIsActive(msisdn);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:9393/crbt/api/subscriber/ivr/checkStatus/"+msisdn);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("failure time over!");
            }
        }
    }
    else {
    }

}
```

*second Api Response in postman*

[image]

*What I expected was first API's response. But its giving me some 415 content type error*

How can I get first API's success json response from second api's response.. I even tried `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders` but couldn't get desired output. What changes I had to do in order to get first Api's response in my second api response.

Comment: Get Request should not "consume" JSON. Some clients do not support sending Data with GET Request. On Redirect to first location given Header will be "lost". If JSON should be the Response, than this method "produces" it.

Comment: Ok.. understood. Yes I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have a strange feeling answering your questions, because I dislike the solution I'll provided. But it might help, so I'll give a try.

Basically, your Controller are just Spring beans, which means you can do is having a dependency, and second controller will call first controller. This will also change your method `verifyOtp` to make it change the return type.

Something like that:

```
...
@Autowired
private FirstController firstController;
...

@GetMapping(value="verifyOtp/{msisdn}/{otp}",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler> verifyOtp(@PathVariable(value="msisdn",required=true)String msisdn,
        @PathVariable(value="otp",required=true)String otp,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    long l_time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long l_time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long l_diff = l_time_end-l_time_start;
    List<Object[]> list = repository.verifyOtp(msisdn,otp);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");


    if(list!=null && list.size()>0) {
        for(Object[] obj:list) {
            String strDate = obj[3]==null?null:obj[3].toString();
            Date dtDb = sdf.parse(strDate);
            Date dtNow = new Date();
            String strDtNow = sdf.format(dtNow);
            dtNow = sdf.parse(strDtNow);

            long ldtDb = dtDb.getTime();
            long ldtNow = dtNow.getTime();
            if(ldtDb>ldtNow) {
                System.out.println("success within time");
                int ii = repository.updateIsActive(msisdn);
                return firstController.fetchOcsByDate2(msidn);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("failure time over!");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
         return null;
    }
}
```

I think you are trying to achieve something uncommon, and to avoid having this dependency between controller, consider:

- Change your use case. Make the second controller returning a `HttpStatus.OK`, and make the client do the next call to the first controller
- Create a service in charge of loading the msidn, which will avoid duplicate code, and keep you in a more standard position to make our evolutions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred due to GetMapping .

```
@GetMapping(value="checkStatus/{msisdn}",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

replace with below in first Api:

```
@GetMapping(value="checkStatus/{msisdn}")
```